# Conda list shows a package but cannot import it

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

Here an issue i'm having on a conda Virtual env. I'm using ubuntu 64b guest on windows 7 host with Virtual Box.

So when i'm doing :

```
source activate MyVirtEnv
conda list |grep visdom
visdom                    0.1.05                        0    conda-forge
```

Seems to be installed right ?
Next step :

```
python
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2017, 11:58:13) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import visdom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'visdom'
>>>
```

Ok, here i'm lost. Why does python does not recognize this package (and it's not the only one). I'm still in my env activated when executing python.

I'm quite new to python so perhaps i'm missing a huge mistake, please be kind :D

Thanks for your help on this one !

Update 1 :

```
deeplearning@deep-learning-virtual-machine:~$ source activate universe
(universe) deeplearning@deep-learning-virtual-machine:~$ python
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2017, 11:58:13) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python35.zip', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.5.egg', '/home/deeplearning/gym', '/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torchvision-0.1.9-py3.5.egg']
>>> sys.executable
'/home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/universe/bin/python'
>>>
```

Comment: Is Python installed in the `MyVirtEnv` environment? What is the output of `sys.path` and `sys.executable` from the Python that you're running?

Comment: Yes, of course python is installed i updated the post with text entry you asked for

Comment: What is the name of your environment? In your example at the top you use `MyVirtEnv`, but in the output below, the environment name seems to be `universe`

Comment: My environment name is universe (MyVirtEnv was a generic name)

Comment: Then can you please show the output of the actual commands that you run to list the packages? For instance, can you `conda list -n universe | grep visdom`?

Comment: `conda list -n universe | grep visdom` :
`visdom                    0.1.05                        0    conda-forge`

Comment: is this figured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138241/list-installed-files-of-a-package

Comment: conda update --all   fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this question in another post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584502/4667568

---

I encountered this issue in my conda environment. The reason is that packages have been installed into two different folders, only one of which is recognised by the Python executable.

~/anaconda2/envs/[my_env]/site-packages ~/anaconda2/envs/[my_env]/lib/python2.7/site-packages

A proved solution is to add both folders to python path, using the following steps in command line (Please replace [my_env] with your own environment):

conda activate [my_env].
conda-develop ~/anaconda2/envs/[my_env]/site-packages
conda-develop ~/anaconda2/envs/[my_env]/lib/python2.7/site-packages (conda-develop is to add a .pth file to the folder so that the Python executable knows of this folder when searching for packages.)
To ensure this works, try to activate Python in this environment, and import the package that was not found.

Answer (score 6):

A couple possibilities occur to me:

## 1. A Potential Path Problem

Your `python` command might refer to a different python than the `python` which is in your active conda environment folder. Check this by running in terminal `which conda` and `which python`. If you get something like the below, you're good here.

```
/anaconda3/bin/conda
/anaconda3/envs/<yourEnvName>/bin/python
```

If you are getting different paths, it is possible your path is messed up. open up your `.bashrc` file and double check lines associated with `python` and `conda`.

Alternatively, reinstall conda.

## 2. A Very Vexing Version Variation

You might have a version/dependency incompatibility issue. This seems unlikely to me as `visdom` is compatible with `python 2.7` onward (I think) and you clearly are using `python 3.5.2`. Nonetheless, this might happen if you are using multiple package managers. Nowadays it is less common, but it does happen occasionally. Try checking this by running `pip show visdom` and/or `conda search --reverse-dependency visdom` or the equivalent for your package manager.

If this is indeed a problem, then I suggest first updating your packages and if that does not work then uninstalling visdom with the original package manager and trying to install with a different package manager.

---

If all of the above fails, start exploring your problem from a new environment. Can you replicate it in the new environment? (I can't). Can you replicate it on another machine? etc...

Keep the internets updated with your problem as we might be able to help some others out!

Comment: #1 was indeed my issue. This post shows how to solve it. TL;DR: `conda deactivate && conda activate foo_env` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733179/why-conda-cannot-call-correct-python-version-after-activating-the-environment/57400535

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Oddly, the output of which seems to make sense: 
(env_name): which conda 
/home/user/Programs/anaconda3/condabin/conda
(env_name):~/Source/medicaldetectiontoolkit$ which python
/home/user/Programs/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
But still having an issue with pip show torch returns the 1.7.1 version while python -c "import torch" fails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be deps related issue see here [github](https://github.com/conda-forge/visdom-feedstock/issues/1) , So maybe You should ensure that Anaconda is up-to-date so that you are working with all the latest package releases. To do this, you should first update the conda utility  run : `conda update conda` , When prompted to do so, type y to proceed with the update. After that update anaconda also  run : `conda update anaconda` Again when prompted to do so, type y to proceed , after updates  finished open new terminal and verify : `conda --version` 
and : `python --version`

- now try reinstalling visdom :`conda install -n universe visdom --force-reinstall` or just update all packages : `conda install -n universe --update-all` .

Answer (score 3):

I unfortunately don't have a "Do exactly this to fix your problem" solution but I would suggest the following steps.  Many seem obvious but I find when sorting these sorts of problems out you have to be certain of each step before moving on.

1. Does the host system, in this case your Ubuntu VM, have multiple versions of python installed?  Are you sure you are using the version you think you're using? Did you check your path variable? You need to be sure you're using your conda installation.
2. Does the host system have different versions of conda installed?
3. It looks like in the activated environment you checked the package is listed in conda.  But is it in the package directory for your virtual environment?  One way to check this is to use the `find` command and specify the base path for your virtual environment.
4. Try forcing the reinstallation of the package.
5. Try using `pip` instead of conda.  If your environment is setup properly `pip` should install packages to the conda path.

*more desperate steps*

6. Make a new virtual environment. Add packages one by one.  Examine what each package is changing.
7. Reinstall conda.
8. Create a new instance of your vm.
9. Make a vm instance from a different image.
10. Make your own image.

This is just one way to troubleshoot the problem.  When possible try to avoid steps 6-10 because they're rather involved.  That said sometimes it's a problem with the vm and not with you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and tried all the given solutions to solve this problem, but they didn't work for me.
Finally, I just added the package install directory to sys.path:

```
import sys  
sys.path.append('/Users/eng/anaconda3/envs/paddle/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

It worked.

Comment: dependent on which shell you use, you can also add the path to the sitepackages in `.bash_profile` (if you use bash) or `.zshrc` (if you use zsh) by: `export PATH:"path/to/site-packages/of/conda/env":$PATH`

Answer (score 2):

Check the files installed for the package as per [List installed files of a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138241/list-installed-files-of-a-package) and compare the list with your `sys.path`.

For `visdom` specifically, looking at the contents of the [available Linux tarball](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/visdom/files), I see that it contains paths like `lib/python3.6/site-packages` -- i.e. it's for Python 3.6 while your Python is 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is a very old question but the same thing just happened to me after doing a conda update conda on my base environment on OSX and the package was numpy. Showed in conda list but could not be imported.  What I did, which fixed it:

```
conda activate base
conda remove numpy
conda install numpy
```

This fixed things.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with file system permissions. This could happen if you have installed the package while under `root`. Try to run

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /home/deeplearning/anaconda3/envs/
```

Drop the `sudo` if you are `root` in your VM terminal.