# List installed files of a package?

Tags: conda

How do I list files that belong to an installed package?

I've done my homework: searched, tried and read conda documentation.

I've looked at `list`, `info`, `search`, and `package` subcommands.

My conda version: 4.3.30

My use cases for this:

1. When a package 'A' installed another package 'B' as its dependency. But B has a bug, or the installation somehow broken, I  want to check which files B installed.
2. An extended use: when commands of A calls some command `b` of B, but I don't know the exact name of B. A 'reverse' search based on `b` to find out B and lets me read more about it.

Comment: Can you explain a usecase as to why you want to do this?

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for asking, I added my use cases to the question.

Comment: Hopefully [this patch](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7457) will get merged eventually, but for now you could apply it locally.

Answer (score 24):

Assuming you have activated the relevant anaconda environment, you can look at the file `${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/<package-name-and-version>-<hash>.json` and look for the `files` element.

(this works with Miniconda on Linux)

Answer (score 7):

Found out that all packages that conda installed are stored under `<root_environment>/pkgs`. One can find out about `root environment` and other information by running `conda info`.

Then to list files that a package has:

`tree <root_environment>/pkgs/<package_name>-<package_version>`

or with `find`, one can also find which downloaded package has the command:

`find <root_environment> -type f -iname 'somecommand'`

`<root_environment>` here is a placeholder for something like `~/anaconda` if one installed anaconda into `~/anaconda`

This solution is rather *nix-specific but it is good enough to me.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is how it may be done from Powershell.

```
$condaInfo = conda info --json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $condaInfo.'package cache'[0] -Filter 'pattern' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

There may be several `$condaInfo.'package cache'` folders.