# Pytorch listed by conda but cannot import

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I am well aware similar questions have been asked
[at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767012/conda-list-shows-a-package-but-cannot-import-it) [twice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180775/getting-import-error-after-installing-packages-through-conda), but none of the answers seams to solve the issue at hand

**My configuration**

Windows 10.0.18363,
Anaconda 4.8.5,
Cuda 10.1.243

```
conda env create -n torch -y python 3.7
conda activate torch
conda install conda -y
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch -y
```

**Here's the bug**

```
python -c "import torch"
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
> ```

**What I tried**

Verifying python and conda

```
where python
```

> ```
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\torch\python.exe
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
> C:\csvn\Python25\python.exe
> ```

```
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

> ['C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages']

```
conda update -n base -y conda
conda update --all -y
conda init
```

> ```
> ...
> No action taken.
> ```

Verifying the torch installation

```
conda list | findstr torch
```

> ```
> _pytorch_select           0.1                       cpu_0
> pytorch                   1.6.0           cpu_py37h538a6d7_0
> torchvision               0.7.0                py37_cu102    pytorch
> ```

Comment: Is the `conda env create` a typo? Shouldn't that be `conda create`? The `conda env create` is only for working with YAML files and does not accept package arguments like `conda create`. Also, what happens with `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\torch\python.exe -c "import torch"`?

Comment: Yes, it's "conda create"

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\torch\python.exe -c "import torch"` does not change the bug

Comment: Strange. The output from the `python -c "import site..."` line seems to indicate that the **base** environment is taking precedent. Not sure why, but that's what I'd focus on resolving. Also, minor tip: `conda  list` already supports a search string, e.g., `conda list torch` should suffice without piping to `findstr`.

Answer (score 1):

More a suggestion than a solution: you can at least reduce the problem surface by [working with a YAML](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) instead of using a series of create/activate/install commands. Create the file:

**torch.yaml**

```yaml
name: torch
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - cudatoolkit=10.2
```

Then simply use

```bash
conda env create -f torch.yaml
```

The result should be equivalent to the environment you indicated, covering both env creation and installation of all packages in a single command.<sup>**1**</sup> Plus, you don't need all those pesky `--yes|-y` flags.

Any problems still persisting are most likely due to PATH or other environment variable management issues.

---

<sub>**[1]** I excluded `conda` from the YAML because that package should only be installed in **base**. Perhaps you meant `anaconda` package?</sub>

Comment: The .YML file is useful for streamlining  the setup process, but it DOES NOT solve aforementioned problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your answers, but none of them allowed me to load torch on my computer. The problem got solved with the new python 3.9. Seems it was a compatibility issue.