# Pyre + Conda: How to add conda packages to Pyre search path?

Tags: python, conda, pyre-check

I am trying to configure the Pyre typechecker to work together with Anaconda. However, pyre is unable to find the packages that I have installed through conda. How can I modify the Pyre config to search in the appropriate anaconda directories?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by adding the path to your conda environment's "site-packages" folder (see [Where is site-packages located in a Conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003994/where-is-site-packages-located-in-a-conda-environment)) to your Pyre configuration file. The file should be in your project folder, named ".pyre_configuration". If it's not there, run `pyre init` to generate it.

Add the following array:

```
"search_path": [
    "/path/to/your/site-packages"
 ]
```