# How to persist conda packages in Docker container

Tags: docker, anaconda, conda

I have a docker container (running Ubuntu) with conda (miniconda) installed. I can create new conda environments in the container but they will not persist the next time I create a new container. I don't want to install the packages as part of the Docker image, so what is the best way to make install packages persist in the container? I imagine some directory needs to be mounted on the host so any `conda install` command installs packages on a host directory and is there the next time a new container is spawned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two locations need to be mounted from outside of the container to make sure conda environment packages don't get removed between container runs:

#### 1. Create directories for python packages outside of container

```
mkdir ~/conda_stuff
mkdir ~/conda_stuff/envs
mkdir ~/conda_stuff/pkgs
```

#### 2. Mount conda env and pkgs directories

```
# assume conda installed in /opt/anaconda in the container
docker run -it -v ~/conda_stuff/envs:/opt/anaconda/envs \
               -v ~/conda_stuff/pkgs:/opt/anaconda/pkgs
```

Now any packages installed in the conda environment via `pip` or `conda install` will persist when the container is exited.

Answer (score 0):

The best way actually would be to create your own image with the required `conda` environment already pre-installed.

This is because `docker` containers are [meant to be ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers), i.e., stopping and removing a container will also throw away any changed state in it and you should be able to just start a new container from the same image.

To store persistent data you have to use `volumes` or `bind-mounts`, see the `docker` storage docs on this: https://docs.docker.com/storage/

In your case you would have to add one or multiple `volumes` to your container and place any changed/installed files there.

Comment: Right, that's the crux of the question. What do I need to mount?

Comment: Please look into the `docker` documentation regarding _how_ to use `volumes`: https://docs.docker.com/storage/
Regarding _where_ to use volumes: this depends heavily on your specific case and can therefor  not be answered with more additional context on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what you already tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003994/where-is-site-packages-located-in-a-conda-environment

Comment: I know how to mount volumes. The question is clear, you don’t understand the use case